# Pseudocode - Calculating the total amount from records

Tags: sum, record, pseudocode

I am currently revising for an exam and received this question:

Write a programme that will continually prompt for an employees number, hours worked, and pay rate. The programme should calculate how much each employee is paid and the total all the pays over all. Your programme is to repeat this process until a sentinel number of 9999 is entered, then the programme should print the number of employees whose pays have been entered, and the total amount overall.

So far I have:

```
PAY_CALCULATOR
   set total_employees to zero
   DISPLAY 'Please enter an employee number'
   GET employee_no
   DOWHILE employee_no != 9999
      add 1 to toal_employee
      DISPLAY 'Please enter hours worked'
      GET pay_rate
```

So as you can see I am missing how to sum the values of each 'pay_rate' received.

Any insight, is there a better way to do this other than a DOWHILE?

Cheers, Benji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Pseudocode,

```
PAY_CALCULATOR
   set total_employees to zero
   set total_pay to zero
   DO
      DISPLAY 'Please enter an employee number'
      GET employee_no
      add 1 to toal_employee
      DISPLAY 'Please enter hours worked'
      GET hours
      Display 'Please enter pay rate'
      GET pay_rate
      SET SAL = hours * pay_rate
      SET total_pay = total_pay + SAL
   WHILE employee_no != 9999
   Display 'Number of Paid Employees', employee_no
   Display 'Total Salary Paid', total_pay
```

For the given problem the number of employees is not predetermined. So `Do While` loop is O.K.

Comment: Of course, I had tried to before but as I have just started asking questions myself (rather than viewing previous answers) I need a reputation to vote up. However you have the tick :) thank you